# How to copy queryset Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I am trying to access queryset of ManyToManyField before and after saving in def save_related(self, request, form, *args, **kwargs) method.
I want to compare them and get new objects, that were added to ManyToManyField.

So, I am getting old queryset with:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, * args, * * kwargs):
    obj = form.instance
    queryset_before = obj.translations.all()
    print(queryset_before)
    super(WordAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, * args, * * kwargs) 
    print(queryset_before)
```

But print(queryset_before) outputs the new, updated queryset after calling super().save_related.

So:

1. How to copy queryset, so that saving will not affect it?
2. Or is there a way to compare old and new values of ManyToManyField more properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get lists of IDs before and after save, then compare these lists:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = form.instance
    list_before = list(obj.translations.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))
    super(WordAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, *args, ** kwargs) 
    list_after = list(obj.translations.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))
    added_ids = [x for x in list_after if x not in list_before]
    removed_ids = [y for y in list_before if y not in list_after]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that printing a queryset will evaluate only a slice of the queryset, and as a result, it won't fill the queryset's internal cache.

You need to completely evaluate the queryset before you make the changes, so that the internal cache is filled. The easiest way to do this is with the `bool()` function:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = form.instance
    queryset_before = obj.translations.all()
    bool(queryset_before)
    print(queryset_before)
    super(WordAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, *args, **kwargs) 
    print(queryset_before)
```

Now both print statements should give you the same results.